# excute mysql query to get records from zoo component zoo version 3 tables

Tags: joomla, components, zoo

How can I execute a custom MySQL query to get records from the Zoo database tables?

Something along the lines of this query:

```
SELECT "64ccc68f-4af3-4c02-8c0f-8ec5977bacb2" 
FROM #__zoo_item 
WHERE application_id=1 and state=1 and type='handy'
```

Comment: Have you read the Joomla documentation on writing database queries?

Comment: i am asking  hare to get "elements" column and this column has json value like this    {
 
 "f04e712e-b17d-4421-83cd-291a7cdd5b6e":  {
  "option":  {
   "0": "videoaufzeichnung"
  }
 },
 "8a473b51-7682-4fcd-ac58-c57a35b610dc":  {
  "0":  {
   "value": "2 Megapixel"
  }
 },
 "b203f386-ed38-43f3-b9e8-211ee720c31b":  {
  "0":  {
   "value": ""
  }
 },
 "52f5424f-1776-4011-97bc-918159221fd6":  {
  "0":  {
   "value": "15"
  }
 },
 "9231e9f5-67d0-4147-9eb9-2c832205e19b":  {
  "0":  {
   "value": "4x"
  }
 }
 
}

Comment: Please read the answers below and study the Joomla documentation for database queries. In future, please be more specific with your requirements so that we don't waste time writing code that you don't need

Answer (score 0):

Read [Documentaion](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase),

```
// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Select all records from the user profile table where key begins with "custom.".
// Order it by the ordering field.
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('user_id', 'profile_key', 'profile_value', 'ordering')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('profile_key') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('\'custom.%\''));
$query->order('ordering ASC');

// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the query you posted in your question, the following would be the Joomla equivalent:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();   
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('64ccc68f-4af3-4c02-8c0f-8ec5977bacb2')))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__zoo_item'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('application_id') . ' = 1 AND '. 
              $db->quoteName('state')  . ' = 1 AND '. 
              $db->quoteName('type')  . ' = ' $db->quoteName('handy'));

$db->setQuery($query);  
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

---

`$results` is an object of the result for your query which you can then do anything you want with.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want very easily using zoo API. I must say they have best API's to fetch the API.Using item get you can get all the information of zoo records, you just need to pass the zoo item id to the function.

```
$app = App::getInstance('zoo');
$item = $app->table->item->get($ITEM_ID); // Zoo Record Id
$Element_Id = "64ccc68f-4af3-4c02-8c0f-8ec5977bacb2"; // One of the text field element id
$element_value = $item->getElement($Element_Id)->getElementData()->get('value');
// $element_value contains the actual value of element id $Element_Id of item id $ITEM_ID.
```

Read this blog to read more. http://atpatil.blogspot.in/2013/04/access-zoo-element-data-anywhere-in.html